# Stop overlaying of features in openlayers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a vector layer and I'm adding multiple features of polygon geometry to it. The code of adding features to the layer is mentioned down below:

```
        let recentPointStyle = new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: '#1c568f',
            }),
            fill: new Fill({
                color: 'rgba(28, 86, 143, 0.5)'
            })
        });

        let pointStyle = new Style({
            fill: new Fill({
                color: 'rgba(124, 252, 0, 0.5)'
            })
        });

        let feature = new Feature({
            geometry: new Polygon([bounds]),
        });

        feature.setStyle(recentPointStyle);

        let allFeatures = [feature];

        let previousBounds = [...this.props.areaVisited];

        for (let i = 0; i < previousBounds.length; i++) {
            let currBound = previousBounds[i];

            let currFeature = new Feature({
                geometry: new Polygon([currBound]),
            });

            currFeature.setStyle(pointStyle);

            allFeatures.push(currFeature);
        }

        previousBounds.push(bounds);

        this.props.dispatch(updateVisitedArea(previousBounds));

        vectorLayer.setSource(new VectorSource({
            features: allFeatures,
            wrapX: false
        }));
```

Now this code is working absolutely fine but when the user goes back to the same area, then the feature is drawn again and it becomes darker and darker and the content of the other layer is not visible. So how can I stop this and maintain the opacity of the layer?

I tried with adding multiple polygons instead of multiple features to the layer. But the same result is coming. This the updated code.

```
               let recentPointStyle = new Style({
                    stroke: new Stroke({
                        color: '#1c568f',
                    }),
                    fill: new Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(28, 86, 143, 0.5)'
                    })
                });

                let pointStyle = new Style({
                    fill: new Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(124, 252, 0, 0.5)'
                    })
                });

                let allPolygons = [];
                let previousBounds =[...this.props.areaVisited];

                for(let i = 0; i < previousBounds.length; i++) {
                    let currBound = previousBounds[i];

                    allPolygons.push(new Polygon([currBound]));
                }

                let feature = new Feature({
                    geometry: new Polygon([bounds]),
                });

                feature.setStyle(recentPointStyle);

                let allFeatures = [feature];

                let currFeature = new Feature({
                    geometry: new MultiPolygon(allPolygons),
                });

                currFeature.setStyle(pointStyle);

                allFeatures.push(currFeature);

                if(!previousBounds.includes(bounds)) {
                    previousBounds.push(bounds);
                }

                this.props.dispatch(updateVisitedArea(previousBounds));
                
                vectorLayer.setSource(new VectorSource({
                    features: allFeatures,
                    wrapX: false
                }));
```

Comment: Instead of adding multiple features you could have a single feature with MultiPolygon geometry and add polygons to the geometry.

Comment: I tried your idea also but the same result is coming. I have added the updated code.

Comment: Yes, looks like OpenLayers does not render polygons in MultiPolygons as a single operation either.  I think you would need a third party utility such as turf https://turfjs.org/docs/#union to combine them and remove overlaps.

Comment: Ya turfjs's union worked for me. Thanks a lot @Mike.